# Combinations from n arrays picking one element from each array

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

Though i found answer to this in the below link, i want to know how to achieve this using itertools in python. [combinations using n arrays by selecting one element from each](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/combinations-from-n-arrays-picking-one-element-from-each-array/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import itertools    

A = [[1], [2,3,4], [5]]
result = []
for c in itertools.product(*A):
    result.append(list(c))
print(result)
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product